# Can anyone suggest some gems/libraries to build a Facebook game using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have started to explore the world of developing Facebook games. I want to start off with what I know ie Ruby on Rails. ( I dont want to use flash)

Can Facebook games be built using RoR? Is there good game engine to start off building Facebook games? Can anyone suggest some gems and techniques?

Answer (score 0):

[facebook sdks](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/)
This is a link that will provide you sdks that you can use for facebook app.
If you want to create any app that wont be needing any user info then you can use absolutely any programming language.Because facebook app is just a iframe embedded in fb.
But if you access use data in order to use in your app then you have to use sdks provided by fb.

Comment: I am not worried about connecting with FB.. My question is how to kick start game development on the server side.. for eg Game engines, Rule engines.. ect..